# N1QL select document id AND a JSON field called "id"

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm running CB Server 4.1 and sending N1QL query through the couchbase-client Java SDK 2.2.1.

My documents have document id (obviously), but also an "id" field embedded inside the document body.

Now I want to select both. None of these works:

```
SELECT id, meta(default).id, name FROM default
SELECT id AS 'internal_id', meta(default).id, name FROM default
SELECT id, meta(default).id AS 'docID', name FROM default
```

Whereas these work:

```
SELECT id, name FROM default
SELECT id AS internal_id, name FROM default
SELECT meta(default).id, name FROM default
```

Is it a current limitation that I cannot name internal fields "id" ?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried `SELECT id, meta(default).id AS docID FROM default` (similar to your third failing statement) and it is working in both Couchbase Server 4.0 and 4.1 (from the **cbq** shell).

However I note that you used single quotes, which is not correct for aliases, so maybe it is that? What is the error message you get, when inspecting the content of `errors()` in your `N1qlQueryResult`?